# I am interesting in finding the answer to the pencil exercise rotating with 2 fingers? Where is the center of rotation when the couple is off center?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I place a pencil on a table and put 2 fingers on 2 sides of the pencil, not in the middle, and I activate my fingers, in opposite directions and to my surprise, the center of rotation is at the center between the fingers, and not in the middle of the pencil. Can somebody explain it please.

Comment: Can you include a diagram or photo? I *think* I understand your setup, but there are some ambiguities.

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: There are instructions on uploading images here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/334566 As an anti-spam measure, low rep members cannot put inline images in their posts, but you can still upload your image (to the Stack Exchange domain on Imgur) and readers can click on the link to view the image.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to your fingers to constrain the movement. If when one of them makes the point of contact move $\mathbf ds$, the other one makes the other point of contact move $-\mathbf ds$, the result is an elementary rotation around the middle point of them.

However if one of the fingers acts only to hold the pencil, while the other one moves in a circle, the rotation is around the fixed finger.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the last few years, I have led a group of orthodontists trying to convince the profession that the center of rotation of a couple placed on a tooth's crown is in the middle of the couple and not in the center of gravity of the tooth. I cannot find even one physicist that supports it. All of them are locked in the idea that the couple's vectors rotate the tooth around a point in the root and not at the mid-couple. The pencil-fingers exercise does not impress them. It's time for a change. The center of rotation of any couple is in the midst of a couple, period!

Comment: @NaphtaliBrezniak It depends on the constraints of the movement, not only on the couple. See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you really apply a couple (equal and opposite forces) to a stationary  object that is free to move, then the centre of mass must remain fixed. Thus   the rotation is about the centre of mass. If you twiddle a pencil in the way you describe, so the centre of mass *moves*, then there must be a net force on the pencil.This means that  your fingers are *not* applying *equal*-and-*opposite* forces, and the applied force system is *not* a couple.

I can't see any application of this to teeth because teeth embedded in the gum are not free to move  and the notion centre of mass of the tooth is irrelevent.

Comment: How can I add a drawing or a movie?